# javascript checkbox checked when clicked away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a Datatable in which i am trying to show a check box and when clicked on any row its checkbox will be checked

this is my table

```
<table class="bt-datatable table table-striped" id="bt-user-datatable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="bt-select-all"></th>
      <th class="text-left">name</th>
      <th class="text-left">gender</th>
      <th class="text-left">class</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
         @user.each do |user|

    %>
            <tr class="bt-users-row">
              <td class="text-left"><input type="checkbox" value="<%= user.id %>"></td>
              <td class="text-left"><%= user.name %></td>
              <td class="text-left"><%= user.gender %></td>
              <td class="text-left"><%= user.class %><div 
            </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and in the javascript i have

```
    $('.bt-users-row').on('click', function(){
            var checkBox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            if (checkBox.is(':checked')){
                checkBox.prop("checked", false);
            }
            else if (!checkBox.is(':checked')) {
                checkBox.prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
```

so in this what i am trying to do is when i click in the row it automatically select the respected checkbox but , i am having an issue is when i click on the checkbox , it does not check it

Comment: can you share a sample of the generated table

Comment: `checkBox.prop("checked", false);` Is this intentionally added inside `if` statement?

Comment: yes it is added so that if checkbox is not checked than it shou;d check

Comment: Try this to check: `checkBox.prop('checked', 'checked')` and this to uncheck `checkBox.prop('checked', '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, when checkbox is checked both the default action and the row check code is executed which negates the action

```
$('.bt-users-row').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
    return;
  }
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', function() {
    return !this.checked;
  });
});
```